# Tracking with Google Tag Manager Ecommerce to Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need your help about GTM and UA.

Like this exemple i catch the Event in Google Analytics that's work fine :

```
// Measure the removal of a product from a shopping cart.
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'removeFromCart',
  'ecommerce': {
    'remove': {                               // 'remove' actionFieldObject measures.
      'products': [{                          //  removing a product to a shopping cart.
          'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
          'id': '12345',
          'price': '15.25',
          'brand': 'Google',
          'category': 'Apparel',
          'variant': 'Gray',
          'quantity': 1
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

In Analytics i can catch the "Event" but where is products data ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The products data is in the datalayer. You can set set the GA tag to read the dataLayer (alternatively you can set it to use an E-commerce-Variable containing the product data). This is just not very visible [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#add), you need to click the little green arrow below the code example to expand the description of how to configure your tag (the example assumes you are using and event to send e-commerce data):

[image]

If you use a GA setting variable you might need to click "override settings" in the GA tag first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.